# React componentWillReceiveProps will receive props not triggering when redux state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've got a store which holds `actions`, these actions are suppose to be looped through each time a new one is added.

I've got a component `MessageListView` which resides in a parent called `MessageView`. When a new action is added to my `socketActions.queue` array, the `componentWillRecieveProps` is suppose to trigger, but it doesn't.

Here is what my reducer looks like:

```
/* Reducer */
const initialState = {
  queue: [{
    type: 'alert',
    action: 'alert',
    completed: false, // Set to true or just delete this object when the action has been completed
    data: {
      message: "the data object dynamically changes based on the type"
    }
  }]
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case ADD_ACTION:
    let queue = state.queue
    // action.data['completed'] = false
    queue.push(action.data)
    console.log("Just updated queue", action.data)

    return {
      ...state,
      queue: queue,
      latestAction: new Date()
    }
```

My component is connected up to the store like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log(state, "State inside messagelistview.js")
  return {
    actionsQueue: state.socketActions.queue,
    latestAction: state.socketActions.latestAction
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ completeAction }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MessageListView);
```

So when I dispatch a new `ADD_ACTION` action, my state updates & `redux-logger` **prints out the new and old state which is telling me that they're the same?!**  . I don't know why it'd be doing this after I've changed the **latestAction** value & queue array. This is why the componentWillRecieveProps isn't working, but I can't figure out why the state is the same?!

Comment: If you use Immutable.js, you tend to not run into these problems anymore. Also, in my opinion, mutating immutable.js' objects looks cleaner than using deconstructing and literals all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% certain if this would solve anything, but I think you aren't properly copying over state.queue into the completely new variable queue.

I'd suggest doing something like:

`let queue = state.queue.slice()`

... and see if anything changes? Right now your `queue` variable is still the same as the `state.queue`

Comment: Awesome!! tbh, I was so scared I gave not good enough of an answer... seeing that you had ~3000 points... This just made my night. :) Thanks again!

Comment: Keep up the good work! This stuff seems to happen, even when you've been programming for a while :D Sometimes you just need a little reminder for the simplest of things

Answer (score 2):

You don't change queue identity in reducer. Try this code:

```
case ADD_ACTION:
  let queue = state.queue
  // action.data['completed'] = false
  queue.push(action.data)
  console.log("Just updated queue", action.data)

  return {
    ...state,
    queue: [...queue], // <-- here we copy array to get new identity
    latestAction: new Date()
  }
```

You should always shallow copy changed objets. See http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments

Comment: Or use slice, as @brian-zhou suggested

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mutating your state when you do this:

```
let queue = state.queue
// action.data['completed'] = false
queue.push(action.data)
```

When you mutate the existing state directly, Redux doesn't detect a difference in state and won't notify your components that the store has changed.

So instead you've the following options to create a new `queue` array:

```
case ADD_ACTION:
  return {
    ...state,
    queue: state.queue.concat(action.data),
    latestAction: new Date()
  }
```

or with ES6 sugar:

```
case ADD_ACTION:
  return {
    ...state,
    queue: [...state.queue, action.data]
    latestAction: new Date()
  }
```

Comment: Yep. I haven't used redux in 2-3 months, I need to brush up on the basics again :').

Answer (score 1):

A connected component does a shallow check (===) whether the state is updated and renders wrapped component only if that check fails. In your case, you're mutating your queue causing the equality the check to pass.

It will work if you change your reducer like this:

```
state.queue = state.queue.concat(action.data);
```

or with ES6 syntax:

```
state = { ...state, queue: [...state.queue, action.data] };
```